# Кабель, провід, шнур, дріт -- відмінності у вживанні

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми

Цікавить різниця у вжитку наступних термінів (визначення із СУМ-11):

- [**КА́БЕЛЬ**](http://sum.in.ua/s/kabelj), ю, чол. *Електричний, телефонний і т. ін. **провід**, уміщений у захисну оболонку.*
- **[ПРО́ВІД](http://sum.in.ua/s/provid)**, воду, чол. ***3**. Металевий провідник, **дріт**, признач. для передавання електричного струму.*
- **[ШНУР](http://sum.in.ua/s/shnur)**, а, чол. **2**. Електричний **провід** з кількох ізольованих жил.
- **[ДРІТ](http://sum.in.ua/s/drit)**, дроту, чол. *Металевий виріб у вигляді гнучкої нитки або тонкого прута.*

Наприклад, *телефонним* може бути як [кабель](http://mukachevo.today/news/kriminal/mukachivec_vkrav_telefonnij_kabel_na_3_tisjachi_griven), так і [провід](http://www.ua.all.biz/uk/provid-telefonnyj-bgg1003328), так і [дріт](http://yak-prosto.com/yak-obzhati-telefonnij-drit/), й навіть [шнур](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/8_%D0%B6%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA). Чи можна спиратись на наявність ізоляції металевого осердя як критерій для вибору того чи іншого слова? Чи варто звертати увагу на щось інше?

Answer (score 8):

"Шнур" має **декілька ізольованих жил**. Зі свого досвіду - шнуром переважно називають проводи, якими вмикають побутові прилади в розетку (наприклад, шнур настільної лампи, пилососу і т.і.). Пам'ятаю, що старі прилади мали шнури, які були оплетені чимось схожим на нитки й справді мали вигляд товстої мотузки. Напевно, тому й називали їх шнурами. Такий самий вигляд мали шнури, що використовувалися для розеток та ламп, які висіли під стелею. Вочевидь, шнур не може бути неізольованим.

[image]

"Дріт", судячи з означення і вживання ("колючий дріт", "дротяна загорожа"), може використовуватися без електрики взагалі. Він **гнучкий, тонкий, металевий**. Здається, що у побуті дротом можна назвати навіть "шнур" - одну або декілька ізольованих жил, навіть у спільній оболонці.

"Провід" призначений для передачі електричного струму. У побуті може означати досить багато варіантів: від дроту без ізоляції, до "шнура" - декількох жил у спільній оболонці. Але головна його риса: він **порівняно тонкий**.

Основна риса "кабелю": має додаткову захисну оболонку. Може мати досить складну структуру (наприклад, додаткове металеве оплетення, щоб захистити від перешкод тощо). Зазвичай, товстий багатожильний кабель не назвуть дротом або проводом. Сьогодні усі комп'ютерні "проводи" називають кабелями (можливо, за виключенням тонких дротів "миші" та клавіатури).

Answer (score 6):

З точки зору електротехніки:

- **провід** - одно- або багатожильний провідник, з ізоляцією або без.
- **кабель** - одно- або багатожильний провідник, обов'язково з ізоляцією. Кабель складається з одного або кількох проводів. 
  Струм до наших розеток підведено по двохпровідному кабелю.
- **шнур** - провідник, що використовується винятково для рухомих з'єднань, в назву закладена рухливість.

Comment: Чи не буде бльш точнішим, на вашу думку, замість `Кабель складається з одного або кількох проводів.` написати `Кабель складається з одного або кількох дротів.`?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Будь ласка, завжди надавайте посилання на поважні джерела, словники тощо. Якщо відповідь зроблено з точки зору електротехніки, то можна підшукати, наприклад, статтю-пояснення або принаймні скріншот веб-магазину, де відповідні предмети зображені поруч із підписами і картинками.

Comment: Зумисне не писав визначення дроту, бо дріт - не електротехнічний термін. Дріт використовується, напр., в сільському господарстві для виготовлення сітки, і т.д.